# Dynamic binding between control in WP7 XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7

I am trying to draw a simple line in WP7 XAML such as the one below. With static coordinate values this works fine.

```
<Line Stroke="White" 
      X1="1" Y1="1" 
      X2="200" Y2="1" />
```

What I need is to bind the coordinate values relative to other controls on the same Canvas based on a matching property value such as its *Id* or *Name*. Once the correct control is bound, I need to get its **Left** and/or **Top** Canvas locations. Using a vague pseudocode, here is what I would like to be able to do...

```
<Line Stroke="White" 
      X1="{Binding Canvas.Left, Source={Binding <a_control_where_a_property_equals_some_value>}}" Y1="1" 
      X2="200" Y2="1" />
```

I've tried a number of binding scenarios with no success. The extra complexity is that this is Windows Phone 7 (WP7) binding and not full blown XAML.

*Note: All the controls are added at runtime so they are not statically defined.*

Any Suggestions???

Comment: What you're asking for isn't really possible per say. You're talking about traversing the visual tree, looking for a control where it's binding have a property with a given value. You'll need to explain better, or post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can hope for is to use [ElementName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname%28v=VS.95%29.aspx). Other than that, you'd need to expose a common property somewhere that both controls would be bound to. Possibly in a view-model, but it depends on your setup.

Sample of ElementName:

```
<Canvas>
    <Line x:Name="line1" Stroke="White" X1="1" Y1="1"  X2="200" Y2="1" />
    <Line Stroke="White" X1="{Binding ElementName=line1, Path=X1}" Y1="10"  X2="200" Y2="1" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, could you possibly provide a sample of how I might get the *Canvas.Left* value using an *ElementName* binding? As an aside, could this be a case where I need to drop XAML and do this part in XNA?

Comment: @Joe - I added a sample. It all depends on what you are doing, so I can't say if another way is better. I would probably recommend having both bind to a common property instead, as that is generally a nicer design (i.e. like a view-model).